# Allow tags between shortcode in comments

Tags: comments, shortcode, code

On my personal blog, I would like commentors to be able to post code using certain shortcodes (eg [html], [css], [js], [php]). I still want to strip tags for comments for security reasons, but allow them between those shortcodes. When I write a test comment, "`[html]<p>sample code</p>[/html]`" becomes "`[html]&lt;p&gt;sample code&lt;/p&gt;[/html]`". To get around this, I came up with the following code but I cannot get it to work. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
function process_code_tags($comment)
{
  $comment = preg_replace_callback('/(\[html\])(.*?)(\[\/html\])/imsu',  create_function('$matches', 'return $matches[0].htmlspecialchars_decode($matches[1]).$matches[2];'), $comment);      
  return $comment;
}
//add_filter('preprocess_comment', 'process_code_tags');
add_filter('comment_text', 'process_code_tags', 9);
```

Comment: Any other ideas besides Christopher's?

Answer (score 1):

You want to allow folks to post code in their comments, like on here were we can just do `<p>something</p>` without having to worry about doing any `&gt;` or `&lt;` stuff?  I think you'll still want those special html characters converted to their respective entities, but you need to stay under the radar to avoid getting the tags stripped out by `wp_filter_kses`.

You'll need to hook into a filter called `pre_comment_content` and convert anything within your shortcode tags to their HTML entity equivalents.

```
<?php
add_filter('pre_comment_text', 'wpse29367_pre_comment_text', 9 );
function wpse29367_pre_comment_text( $text )
{
    $text = preg_replace_callback( 
        '/(\[html\])(.*?)(\[\/html\])/i', 
        create_function( '$matches', 'return $matches[1] . htmlspecialchars( $matches[2] ) . $matches[3];' ),
        $text
    );
    return $text;
}
```

Then you can decode them or whatever in the shortcode function you create:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'wpse29367_add_shortcode' );
function wpse29367_add_shortcode()
{
    add_shortcode( 'html', 'wpse29367_shortcode_cb' );
}

function wpse29367_shortcode_cb( $atts, $content = NULL )
{
    /**
     * decode html entities here if you want
     * eg: 
     * return htmlspecialchars_decode( $content );
     */
}
```

The final piece of the puzzle, adding the `do_shortcode` filter to comment_text.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'do_shortcode' );
```

You could make this work very well for your visitors by using a plugin like [SyntaxHighlighter Evolved](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/), and just using the first bit of code I posted along with adding the `do_shortcode` filter to `comment_text`.

*Note: didn't test any of the above.  Copy and paste with caution.*

Comment: Thanks Chris. I am using Syntax Highlighter Evolved. That part is working fine, it's just displaying the entities.